# Compare multiple algorithms with sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to set up a scikit-learn pipeline to simplify my work. The problem I'm facing is that I don't know which algorithm (random forest, naive bayes, decision tree etc.) fits best so I need to try each of them and compare the results. However does pipeline only take one algorithms at a time? For example below pipeline only takes in SGDClassifier() as the algorithm.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
('vect', CountVectorizer()),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
('clf', SGDClassifier()),])
```

What should I do if I want to compare different algorithms? Can I do something like this?

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
('vect', CountVectorizer()),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
('clf', SGDClassifier()),
('classifier', MultinomialNB()),])
```

I don't want to break it down into two pipelines because the preprocess of the data is super time consuming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't look like this usecase is supported. On another note, you can probably speed things up by using `TfidfVectorizer` instead of `CountVectorizer` + `TfidfTransformer`

Comment: That was just an example from online. but thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Improving on Bruno's answer, what most people really want to do is be able to pass in ANY classifier (not have to hard-code each one) and also any parameters for each classifier. Here is an easy way to do this:

## Create a switcher class that works for any estimator

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
class ClfSwitcher(BaseEstimator):

def __init__(
    self, 
    estimator = SGDClassifier(),
):
    """
    A Custom BaseEstimator that can switch between classifiers.
    :param estimator: sklearn object - The classifier
    """ 

    self.estimator = estimator


def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
    self.estimator.fit(X, y)
    return self


def predict(self, X, y=None):
    return self.estimator.predict(X)


def predict_proba(self, X):
    return self.estimator.predict_proba(X)


def score(self, X, y):
    return self.estimator.score(X, y)
```

Now you can pass in anything for the estimator parameter. And you can optimize any parameter for any estimator you pass in as follows:

## Perform hyper-parameter optimization

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('clf', ClfSwitcher()),
])

parameters = [
    {
        'clf__estimator': [SGDClassifier()], # SVM if hinge loss / logreg if log loss
        'tfidf__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
        'tfidf__stop_words': ['english', None],
        'clf__estimator__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet', 'l1'),
        'clf__estimator__max_iter': [50, 80],
        'clf__estimator__tol': [1e-4],
        'clf__estimator__loss': ['hinge', 'log', 'modified_huber'],
    },
    {
        'clf__estimator': [MultinomialNB()],
        'tfidf__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
        'tfidf__stop_words': [None],
        'clf__estimator__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-1),
    },
]

gscv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=5, n_jobs=12, return_train_score=False, verbose=3)
gscv.fit(train_data, train_labels)
```

### How to interpret `clf__estimator__loss`

`clf__estimator__loss` is interpreted as the `loss` parameter for whatever `estimator` is, where `estimator = SGDClassifier()` in the top most example and is itself a parameter of `clf` which is a `ClfSwitcher` object.

Comment: Ingenious approach. Basically making the classifier "just another hyperparameter to tune". Bravo.

Answer (score 8):

## Preprocessing

You say that preprocessing the data is very slow, so I assume that you consider the TF-IDF Vectorization part of your preprocessing.

**You could preprocess just once.**

```
X = <your original data>

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
X = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(X)
```

Once you have your new transformed data, you can continue using it and choose the best classifier.

## Optimizing the TF-IDF Transformer

While you could transform your data with `TfidfVectorizer` just once, I would not recommend it, because the `TfidfVectorizer` has hyper-parameters itself, which can also be optimized. In the end, you want to optimize the whole `Pipeline` together, because the parameters for the `TfidfVectorizer in`a `Pipeline [TfidfVectorizer, SGDClassifier]` can be different than for a `Pipeline [TfidfVectorizer, MultinomialNB]`.

## Creating a custom classifier

To give an answer to what you asked exactly, you could make your own estimator that has the choice of model as a hyper-parameter.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator


class MyClassifier(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, classifier_type: str = 'SGDClassifier'):
        """
        A Custome BaseEstimator that can switch between classifiers.
        :param classifier_type: string - The switch for different classifiers
        """
        self.classifier_type = classifier_type


    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if self.classifier_type == 'SGDClassifier':
            self.classifier_ = SGDClassifier()
        elif self.classifier_type == 'MultinomialNB':
            self.classifier_ = MultinomialNB()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unkown classifier type.')

        self.classifier_.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def predict(self, X, y=None):
        return self.classifier_.predict(X)
```

You can then use this customer classifier in your `Pipeline`.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('clf', MyClassifier())
])
```

You can then you `GridSearchCV` to choose the best model. When you create a parameter space, you can use double underscore to specify the hyper-parameter of a step in your `pipeline`.

```
parameter_space = {
    'clf__classifier_type': ['SGDClassifier', 'MultinomialNB']
}

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

search = GridSearchCV(pipeline , parameter_space, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
search.fit(X, y)

print('Best model:\n', search.best_params_)
```

Comment: @Sergei Danielian, with this setup, I am bit confused about how to set up the hyper-parameters for both classifiers

Comment: @GSA, sorry, ask Bruno instead - he is the answer's author

Comment: @Bruno Lubascher, with this setup, I am bit confused about how to set up the hyper-parameters for both classifiers

Answer (score 0):

Just starting out on my Python journey. The ideas below are not my own. All the credit goes to David S. Batista `https://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/23/model_optimization/` who modified code by Panagiotis Katsaroumpas and shared it.

What I have done is modify David's code a bit by adding a user defined score and a preprocessing step that includes data imputation and scaling prior to model estimation. So here goes:

```
# import the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
Imputer = IterativeImputer(max_iter=10, random_state=15)      # I used a custom wrapper

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from inne import IsolationNNE

## create the scoring for the models and save it to file
## in current working directory as 'scorers.py'
# def scorer_decision(estimator, X):
#     return np.nanmean(estimator.decision_function(X))

## import decision function score saved as .py file
## into working directory of project
from scorers import scorer_decision

class EstimatorSelectionHelper:

    def __init__(self, models, params):
        if not set(models.keys()).issubset(set(params.keys())):
            missing_params = list(set(models.keys()) - set(params.keys()))
            raise ValueError("Some estimators are missing parameters: {}".format(missing_params))
        self.models = models
        self.params = params
        self.keys = models.keys()
        self.grid_searches = {}
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None, cv=5, n_jobs=3, verbose=1, scoring=scorer_decision, refit=True):
        for key in self.keys:
            print("Running GridSearchCV for %s." % key)
            model = self.models[key]
            params = self.params[key]
            gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, 
                              param_grid=params, 
                              cv=cv, 
                              n_jobs=n_jobs,
                              verbose=verbose, 
                              scoring=scoring,
                              refit=refit,
                              return_train_score=True)
            gs.fit(X,y=None)
            self.grid_searches[key] = gs    

    def score_summary(self, sort_by='mean_score'):
        def row(key, scores, params):
            d = {
                 'estimator': key,
                 'min_score': min(scores),
                 'max_score': max(scores),
                 'mean_score': np.mean(scores),
                 'std_score': np.std(scores),
            }
            return pd.Series({**params,**d})

        rows = []
        for k in self.grid_searches:
            print(k)
            params = self.grid_searches[k].cv_results_['params']
            scores = []
            for i in range(self.grid_searches[k].cv):
                key = "split{}_test_score".format(i)
                r = self.grid_searches[k].cv_results_[key]        
                scores.append(r.reshape(len(params),1))

            all_scores = np.hstack(scores)
            for p, s in zip(params, all_scores):
                rows.append((row(k, s, p)))

        df = pd.concat(rows, axis=1).T.sort_values([sort_by], ascending=False)

        columns = ['estimator', 'min_score', 'mean_score', 'max_score', 'std_score']
        columns = columns + [c for c in df.columns if c not in columns]

        return df[columns]
    

# list of numeric features to impute
numeric_columns = list(Xtrain.select_dtypes(include = 'number').columns)

# pipeline for processing numerical feeatures
numeric_transformer = Pipeline([ 
                                ('imputer', Imputer()),
                                ('scaler', StandardScaler()) 
                               ])

# column transformer
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer([ 
                                        ('numeric_pipeline', numeric_transformer, numeric_columns) 
                                       ])
    

# grid search parameters for models
num_estimators = np.linspace(100, 200, num = 5, endpoint = True).astype(int)
max_samples = np.linspace(0.70, 1.00, num = 5)
contamination = np.linspace(0.04, 0.10, num = 5, endpoint = True)
max_features = np.arange(start = 1, stop = Xdata.shape[1]+1, step = 1)

# estimators to use
models1 = {
    'iforest': IsolationForest(n_jobs = -1, random_state = 3),
    'iNNE': IsolationNNE(random_state = 3)
    }

# parameters
params1 = { 
    # isolation forest grid parameters
     'iforest': { 
                 'n_estimators': num_estimators,
                 'max_samples': max_samples,
                 'contamination': contamination,
                 'max_features': max_features,
                 'bootstrap': [False]
                 },
    # inne grid parameters
    'iNNE': {
             'n_estimators': num_estimators,
             'max_samples': max_samples,
             'contamination': contamination
            }
          }

## run the models
# create EstimatorSelectionHelper by passing models and parameters
estimators = EstimatorSelectionHelper(models1, params1)

# create pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([ 
                 ('ct', column_transformer),
                 ('models', estimators) 
                ])

pipe.fit(Xdata)

## get summary output
output = pipe.named_steps.models.score_summary(sort_by = 'max_score')
output.head()
```