# GridSearchCV use of multiple classifiers: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'estimator'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, grid-search

happy friday.

I am trying to create a pipeline for multiple classifiers.

I started off by finding [this](http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/23/model_optimization/)

Unfortunately it is a little bit above my skill level right now and I could not get it to work properly, I ended up going the more verbose and lengthy way:

```
def multi_tester(X_train, y_train):
    pipe_1 = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier()))
    ])

    pipe_2 = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', ExtraTreesClassifier())
    ])

    pipe_3 = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', AdaBoostClassifier())
    ])

    pipe_4 = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', GradientBoostingClassifier())
    ])

    pars = [
        {'clf': [MultiOutputClassifier()]},
        {'clf': [ExtraTreesClassifier()]},
        {'clf': [AdaBoostClassifier()]},
        {'clf': [GradientBoostingClassifier()]}
    ]

    pips = [pipe_1, pipe_2, pipe_3, pipe_4]
    pip_names = ['MultiOutputClassifier', 'ExtraTreesClassifier', 'AdaBoostClassifier', 'GradientBoostingClassifier']

    scoring = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 
           'F1': metrics.make_scorer(metrics.f1_score), 
           'recall': metrics.make_scorer(metrics.recall_score),
           'precision': metrics.make_scorer(metrics.precision_score)}


    print ("starting Gridsearch")
    for i in range(len(pars)):
        gs = GridSearchCV(pips[i], pars[i], scoring = scoring, 
                          cv = 5, verbose=2, refit=False, n_jobs=-1, return_train_score = True)
        gs = gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print ("finished Gridsearch for: ", pip_names[i])
        print (gs.best_score_)
```

Unfortunately I think I declared either the estimators or the params incorrectly because when I run this:

```
multi_tester(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-fd713f1ef4da> in <module>
----> 1 multi_tester(X_train, y_train)

<ipython-input-30-287aec48dbda> in multi_tester(X_train, y_train)
     25 
     26     pars = [
---> 27         {'clf__estimator': [MultiOutputClassifier()]},
     28         {'clf__estimator': [ExtraTreesClassifier()]},
     29         {'clf__estimator': [AdaBoostClassifier()]},

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'estimator'
```

I've gone over the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and thought the way I instantiated it covered the default params but, I clearly got it wrong.

If you have any suggestions or input on how I could deal with this it would be greatly appreciated.

-#####################################################################################################-

Also for future reference in case you end up finding stackoverflow to attempt the David Batista code, this is how far I got:

and here are some SO questions that I thought were really helpful:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285973/pipeline-multiple-classifiers)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507651/multiple-classification-models-in-a-scikit-pipeline-python)

For now I can't troubleshoot it but it seems like figuring out the params in  a way that they are a list will fix the issues.

```
class ClfSwitcher(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, estimator = SGDClassifier(),):
        """
        A Custom BaseEstimator that can switch between classifiers.
        :param estimator: sklearn object - The classifier
        """ 

        self.estimator = estimator


    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.estimator.fit(X, y)
        return self


    def predict(self, X, y=None):
        return self.estimator.predict(X)


    def predict_proba(self, X):
        return self.estimator.predict_proba(X)


    def score(self, X, y):
        return self.estimator.score(X, y)
```

And then I defined some of the parameters for the models I want to look at like this:

```
search_space = [{
    'ExtraTreesClassifier': { 'n_estimators': [200] },
    'RandomForestClassifier': { 'n_estimators': [200] },
    'AdaBoostClassifier':  { 'n_estimators': [200] },
    'GradientBoostingClassifier': { 'n_estimators': [200], 'learning_rate': [0.8, 1.0] },
    'SVC': [{'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10]}, {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C': [1, 10], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001]}],
    'MultiOutputClassifier': { 'n_estimators': [200] }
    }]
```

finally the pipeline was defined in this way:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', ClfSwitcher())
    ])
```

and the respective scoring:

```
scoring = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 
           'F1': metrics.make_scorer(metrics.f1_score), 
           'recall': metrics.make_scorer(metrics.recall_score),
           'precision': metrics.make_scorer(metrics.precision_score)}
```

but when I run the grid search it returns an error:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipeline, param_grid = search_space, cv = 10, scoring = scoring, return_train_score = True,
                   n_jobs = -1, refit = 'AUC')



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7b76d42489a9> in <module>
      1 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipeline, param_grid = search_space, cv = 10, scoring = scoring, return_train_score = True,
----> 2                    n_jobs = -1, refit = 'AUC')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in __init__(self, estimator, param_grid, scoring, n_jobs, iid, refit, cv, verbose, pre_dispatch, error_score, return_train_score)
   1143             return_train_score=return_train_score)
   1144         self.param_grid = param_grid
-> 1145         _check_param_grid(param_grid)
   1146 
   1147     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _check_param_grid(param_grid)
    369                 raise ValueError("Parameter values for parameter ({0}) need "
    370                                  "to be a sequence(but not a string) or"
--> 371                                  " np.ndarray.".format(name))
    372 
    373             if len(v) == 0:

ValueError: Parameter values for parameter (ExtraTreesClassifier) need to be a sequence(but not a string) or np.ndarray.
```

Comment: so what's your question? if you have one

Comment: @NicolasGervais how to handle the estimator error mentioned in the title and that I extended under   ```multi_tester(X_train, y_train)``` and 
"I get the following error  "